# mod rewrite not working on Server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server

So I need to redirect all the request with the url starting with 'ordermodel'. This works on my localhost but when I uploaded it on my Server it did not redirect to index.php. Below is my htaccess.

```
                    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                        RewriteEngine On
                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !  
                        (aHirasTailoredFit.php|admin_CI)
                        RewriteRule ordermodel index.php [QSA,L]
                    </IfModule>
```

This is my local url: http://localhost/BACKUP-HIRAS-JUNE-27-2016/HirasTailoredFit-DEV/ - it works here

but not here

http://www.example.com/QA-OrderSheet/aHirasTailoredFit.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow overwrite there ..

```
 <Directory "/path/to/document/root/">
   AllowOverride All
   Allow from All
 </Directory>
```

and Please confirm that you remove # from Httpdconfig file from Apache folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am new on this server thing, where should i put those code above? is that a separate file?

Comment: are you using linux or window ?

Comment: I am using windows. It's working locally but not working on my server

Comment: first of all you have to check on server that Mod_rewrite is Enable or not 

To check that if mod_rewrite module is enabled,
create a new php file in your root folder on server.
Enter the following
phpinfo();
Access your created file from your browser.
find out in loaded module Search for 'mod_rewrite'. If it is enabled you see it as 'Loaded Modules'

Comment: It is enabled, I think I am missing this part '  RewriteRule ordermodel index.php [QSA,L]'

Comment: I dont knwo how to make Rewrite rule